# How to know admob automitic refresh enabled on server side from client side?

Tags: android, ios, admob

I wanna know this to determine if i need to refresh ad from client side? When automatic refresh enabled in server side, then I will disable client side refresh logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured an auto refresh period in your Admob dashboard (on the server) then you do **not** need to enact any client client logic to refresh your ads, the Admob library will take care of it automatically.